# MySQL and Unity: Access Denied

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read a database on a MySQL server, with Unity.

My string connection in Unity is:

`string connectdb = "server=**.**.**.**;" +"user=PLAYER;"+"database=****_database;"+"port=15;"+"password=psw"+ "CharSet = utf8mb4;";`

And when I try to connect a get the error :

> Access denied for user 'PLAYER'@'*********************' (using password: YES)

In MySQL server I grant all privileges to 'PLAYER', to any IP address. As you can see, it work on localhost:

[image: As you can see, it work on localhost]

And of course, I comment the line of blind address:

[image: ok]

And it denied access. Why might this be?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're specifying a password in your connection string: `"password=psw"`

Change this for null or remove the password key entirely.